# PowerPoint macro to get the date of the next Thursday from the current date

Tags: vba, date, macros, powerpoint

I'm trying to get the date of next Thursday from the current date and write it in the first slide. So far I have the current date but I didn't find how to get the date of the next Thursday. For example I open my presentation on Tuesday 23.08.2016 and when my macro runs I want to get 25.08.2016 (which corresponds to Thursday) on the first slide.

So far I have:

```
Set objPPTX = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPTX.Visible = True
'Adding Date on First Slide 
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
    PPApp.Visible = True
     Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' Set PPshape = PPSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=220, Top:=150, Width:=270, Height:=75)
 Set PPshape1 = PPSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=20, Top:=150, Width:=680, Height:=70)
 With PPshape1
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "PT PM Weekly"
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Verdana"
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 48
 End With

 Set PPshape = PPSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=350, Top:=150, Width:=680, Height:=70)
With PPshape


Todate = DateValue(Now)
oldWeekDay = Weekday(Now)
Select Case Thursday

Case oldWeekDay = 1
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 4, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 2
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 3, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 3
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 2, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 4
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 1, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 5
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 6
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now - 1, " dd.mm.yyyy")
Case oldWeekDay = 7
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now - 2, " dd.mm.yyyy")

End Select

.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Verdana"
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 48
End With
```

but at the end i just get +4 from the current date so I think that the problem is in the Case structure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help, read the WeekDay help

```
Function NEXT_THURSDAY(dtFrom As Date) As Date

Dim intCurrentDay As Integer

intCurrentDay = Weekday(dtFrom, vbThursday)

NEXT_THURSDAY = DateAdd("d", 8 - intCurrentDay, dtFrom)

End Function
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i didn't exactly understand what i have to do? I don't find the solution for this

Comment: textframe.textrange.text = NEXT_THURSDAY(now)  would be how you'd use, add this code to your VBA code, in a new module if you like and then use like so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the syntax of the `Select Case` statement.

You begin with

```
Select Case Thursday
```

but you haven't defined `Thursday`, so VBA will assume this new variable is equal to 0.

Your first case is then

```
Case oldWeekDay = 1
```

but `Case` should be followed by a *value*, not a comparison. VBA is evaluating the comparison `oldWeekDay = 1` and if it is false, converting that to a value of 0. So the first case will always execute, unless `oldWeekDay` is actually equal to 1.

What I think you wanted to write was

```
Select Case oldWeekDay
    Case 1
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 4, " dd.mm.yyyy")
```

and so on.

Note that if you added the statement `Option Explicit` at the top of your VBA module, you would instead have got a `Variable not defined` error for the `Select Case` line. It's highly recommended to always use `Option Explicit` for this sort of reason.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is a very good suggestion! I agree, it should always be used.